# Sitecore adding field labels to name value list

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

I am trying to display field titles above the appropriate columns in a name value list in Sitecore.

e.g. So instead of this
[image]

The name value list would look like this
[image]

Is there an easy method of achieving this apart from writing a custom control?

Comment: I don't think there is a way without a custom control or injecting in some HTML into the Editor using Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out of the box support for applying a label to the values in a name value list, as @jammykam mentioned.

Since what you are storing would not typically be handled as key/value data, the name value list type might not be the best fit for what you are doing - think what you would have to do if you needed to add extra information e.g. title.  I would suggest creating a simple template for 'person details' and then add 'people' items as sub-items of your existing item.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to give the authors a hint regarding the input fields and the best way to do that is using the "Short Description" field in "Help" section of the template under Standard Values. You can possibly enter something like  as a hint.

A less optimal option would be to set up standard values for that field so the authors always have a value that suggests the type of input value for key and value.